# Javascript convert time to brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, string-formatting, string-parsing

I have a javascript string and I would like to convert them into like this:

```
08:00:00 -> [8,0]

07:30:00 -> [7,30]

14:00:00 -> [14,0]

16:25:00 -> [16,25]
```

i'm not sure how to go about doing this.
what is the fastest and most efficient way to do this in javascript?

Comment: `split` by `:` and `map` to `Number`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: `"16:25:00".split(":").slice(0,2)`

Comment: What about seconds (`"08:30:45"`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timeArray = "16:25:00".split(":", 2).map(Number);
```

Comment: learned something new myself...didn't realize split() had a limit option +1